# Python web scraping empty result

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I followed a youtube tutorial on web scraping to scrape this website https://books.toscrape.com/ but i'm getting an empty result

```
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    all_books = []
    
    url = "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html"
    def get_page(url):
        page = requests.get(url)
        status = page.status_code
        soup = bs(page.text, "lxml")
        return [soup, status]

def get_links(soup):
    links = []
    listings = soup.find_all(class_="product_pod")

def get_links(soup):
    links = []
    listings = soup.find_all(class_="product_pod")

    def extract_info(links):
        for listing in listings:
            bk_lnk = listing.find("h5").a.get("href")
            base_url = "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue"
            cmplt_lnk = base_url + bk_lnk
            links.append(cmplt_lnk)
        return links

def extract_info(links):
    for link in links:
        res = requests.get(link).text
        book_soup = bs(res, "lxml")
        title = book_soup.find(class_ = "col-sm-6 product_main").h1. text.strip()
        price = book_soup.find(class_ = "col-sm-6 product_main").p. text.strip()
        book = {"title": title, "price": price}
        all_books.append(book)


        pg = 1
        while True:
            url = f"http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{pg}.html"
            soup_status = get_page(url)
            if soup_status[1] == 200:
                print (f"scraping page {pg}")
                extract_info(get_links(soup_status[0]))
                pg += 1
            else: 
                print("The End")
                break

df = pd.DataFrame(all_books)

print (df)
```

here's the result am getting

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

my colab notebook link

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Lyvwt_WLpE9tqy1qheZg80N70CFSsk-E?usp=sharing

Comment: You have just defined the functions and not used them yet. Since no function has been called, the dataframe is obviously empty

Comment: how do i call the function please

Comment: You call a function by its name and providing appropriate arguments. There are countless tutorials online if you just google "python functions". I suggest that you refer to one of those, they would explain it nicely with examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_links(soup):
    links = []
    listings = soup.find_all(class_="product_pod")

    def extract_links():
        for listing in listings:
           bk_lnk = listing.find("h3").a.get("href")
           base_url = "https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/"
           cmplt_lnk = base_url + bk_lnk
           links.append(cmplt_lnk)
        return links
    return extract_links()

def extract_info(links):
    for link in links:
       res = requests.get(link).text
       book_soup = bs(res, "lxml")
       title = book_soup.find(class_ = "col-sm-6 product_main").h1.text.strip()
       price = book_soup.find(class_ = "col-sm-6 product_main").p.text.strip()
       book = {"title": title, "price": price}
       all_books.append(book)

pg = 45

while True:
    url = f"https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{pg}.html"
    soup_status = get_page(url)
    if soup_status[1] == 200:
        print (f"scraping page {pg}")
        extract_info(get_links(soup_status[0]))
        pg += 1
    else: 
        print("The End")
        break
```

Comment: you need to call the function and the "while True:" must be in outside the scope of extract_info function.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is empty . Need to call your functions .. such as

Get_page(url) which should return a list which you can use soup in your subsequent function ..